# Finding a linear map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto\mathbb{R}^3$ given preimage and image

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I've been trying to understand how to solve a question in a Linear Algebra exam I've taken today, but I can't seem to understand where to even start. The question is:

*Determine a linear map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto\mathbb{R}^3$ that maps the affine subspace spanned by the plane $x-3y+z-1=0$ to the line $\begin{cases}x+y=0\\y=z-1\end{cases}$*

My greatest hurdle seems to be dealing with the fact that the plane and the line are translated. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $R$ is the field of real numbers?

Comment: You can first translate the plane to be the $x-y$ plane, if you want. Just see where the line goes to.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'll try as you said. Is it right to say that the matrix associated to this linear map, if it exists, has rank 2?

Comment: if the plane is spanned by the vectors a and b, and the line by c then just define a linear map that maps a to c and b to 0.

Comment: I’m not sure that you can say that its rank is exactly 2, but it is at most 2.

Comment: @amd Thanks. So the rank is at most 2 due to the line being an affine subspace, and not a line by the origin. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: It doesn’t have full rank because it collapses a two-dimensional affine space to a one-dimensional one.

Comment: Since the image of any such $\phi$ contains an affine line not through the origin, it contains the plane it spans, so $\operatorname{rank} \phi \geq 2$, giving equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $x-3y+z-1=0$ can be written as

$$\langle (x,y,z), (1,-3,1)\rangle = 1. \tag{1}$$

A solution is $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,0,0)$.
We can hence rewrite it as

$$\langle (x,y,z) - (x_0,y_0,z_0), (1,-3,1)\rangle = 0$$

This brings to mind the plane through the origin and perpendicular to $(1,-3,1)$,

$$\langle (a,b,c), (1,-3,1)\rangle = 0. \tag{2}$$

Hence, the affine plane defined by $(1)$ is obtained from the plane through the origin defined by $(2)$ via a translation by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

---

Similarly, let's consider the line $R$ given by equations $\begin{cases}x+y=0\\y=z-1\end{cases}$.
We have two solutions in $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$.
The line can hence be parametrized as

\begin{align}
r(t)
&= (0,0,1)+t\cdot\Big((1,-1,0)-(0,0,1)\Big)
\\&=
(0,0,1)+t\cdot(1,-1,-1).
\end{align}

$R$ is hence obtained from the line $T$ through the origin and with direction $(1,-1,-1)$ via a translation by $(0,0,1)$.

---

A linear transformation takes a subspace to a subspace, and an affine space to an affine space.
It is hence enough to require that $\phi$ takes $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to $(0,0,1)$ and plane $(2)$ to line $R$.

---

The plane $(2)$ is spanned by any two linearly independent solutions.
If $(a,b,c) = (x,y,z) -$ $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, we can easily find the linearly independent solutions

$$(a_1,b_1,c_1) = (1,0,-1)\\
(a_2,b_2,c_2) = (3,1,0).$$

---

We finally have everything we need.
We just need to find a linear transformation $\phi$ such that

- $\phi(1,0,0) = (0,0,1)$: $\phi$ takes an offset of the affine plane to an offset of the affine line
- $\phi(1,0,-1) = \phi(3,1,0) = (1,-1,-1)$: $\phi$ takes the plane through the origin parallel to $(1)$ to the line through the origin parallel to $R$

Notice that $\{(1,0,0), (1,0,-1), (3,1,0)\}$ is a linealy independent set $($and hence a basis for $\mathbb R^3)$, so indeed this uniquely determines $\phi$.

---

I calculate $\phi(v) =  \pmatrix{0&1&-1\\0&-1&1\\1&-4&2}\,v$.
If $v=(x,y,z)$ then

$$\phi(v) = (y-z, -y+z,x-4y+2z)$$

Writing $\phi(v) = (\phi_x, \phi_y, \phi_z)$, notice that $\phi_x+\phi_y=0$.

Moreover, if $x-3y+z-1=0$ $($that is, $v$ lies in the plane$)$, then $\phi_z = (x-3y+z)-y+z =$ $1 + \phi_y$, or $\phi_y = \phi_z - 1$.
In other words, $\phi(v)$ satisfies our equation for the line.

Comment: Hmm... the method looks good, but something seems off in the calculations. When I apply this $\phi$ to a generic point on the plane, the result isn’t a point on the line.

Comment: @amd Right at the beginning, an error sign! Will fix it. EDIT: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Still not working for me, unfortunately. I’ll double-check my calculations.

Comment: @amd Okay, I was wrongly mapping the translated generators of the plane to the directional generator of the line. This should be good now.

Comment: Works for me now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the miscalculations.

Answer (score 3):

I often find working with homogeneous coordinates in a projective space convenient for problems involving flats in $\mathbb R^n$: affine transformations become linear ones and straightforward matrix computations can usually be brought to bear.

In this framework, the equation of the plane says that it is the null space of the matrix $\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&1&-1\end{bmatrix}}$ a basis for which can be found by inspection: it is spanned by $\{(1,0,0,1)^T,(-1,0,1,0)^T,(3,1,0,0)^T\}$. Similarly, the line is the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix},$$ which is spanned by $\{(1,-1,0,1)^T,(-1,1,1,0)^T\}$. This gives us all of the pieces that we need to construct the required map.

Affine transformations leave the plane at infinity fixed, so we must take care to map points at infinity only to points at infinity. We also want to leave the origin fixed so that the transformation will be linear. This suggests defining the mappings $$\begin{align}(1,0,0,1)^T &\to (1,-1,0,1)^T \\ (-1,0,1,0)^T &\to (-1,1,1,0)^T \\ (3,1,0,0)^T &\to (-1,1,1,0)^T \\ (0,0,0,1)^T &\to (0,0,0,1)^T \end{align}.$$ The matrix of the transformation of $\mathbb P^3$ that achieves this is then simply $$ \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-1&0\\-1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&3&0 \\ 0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-4&0&0 \\ -1&4&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ The last row of this matrix verifies that it is indeed an affine transformation and the last column tells us that it is linear, as required. The matrix of the corresponding linear transformation of $\mathbb R^3$ is therefore the upper-left $3\times3$ submatrix. This map has rank 2, as suspected. Other choices of basis for the line and plane might produce different maps.

To verify, we can use the spanning set for the plane to construct a parameterization of it in $\mathbb R^3$, namely $(1,0,0)+\lambda(-1,0,1)+\mu(3,1,0)$. Applying the above map to this point gives $(1-\lambda-\mu, \lambda+\mu-1,\lambda+\mu)$, which clearly satisfies the defining equations of the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I could accept both answers :)

Comment: This is essentially the same approach as Fimpellizieri’s but packaged differently. The points at infinity are the projective counterparts of the generators of the two flats; we map a point on the plane to a point on the line, the plane’s generators to the line’s generator, and the origin to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Find a linear transformations $S$ that maps the given plane $\Pi$ onto the reference plane $\Pi_0 := \{z = 1\}$ and a map $T$ that maps a reference line $\ell_0 := \{x = 0, z = 1\}$ onto the given line $\ell$, so that the line is the image of the plane under the evident linear projection $\pi: (x, y, z) \mapsto (0, y, z)$. Then, by construction, $$\boxed{\phi := T \circ \pi \circ S} \qquad \textrm{(surjectively) maps} \qquad \Pi \stackrel{S}{\mapsto} \Pi_0 \stackrel{\pi}{\mapsto} \ell_0 \stackrel{T}{\mapsto} \ell$$
as desired.

- To find a map $S$, note that if we denote $z' := x - 3 y + z$, then $\Pi = \{z' = 1\}$, so we need to find $S$ such that $\pmatrix{1&-3&1} S = \pmatrix{0&0&1}$, and making the easiest choices gives $$S = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\1&3&1} .$$ The above condition guarantees that $S$ maps $\Pi$ into the reference plane, and $S$ is (visibly) nondegenerate so it maps onto that plane.
- To find a map $T$, note that we can parameterize the reference line via $t \mapsto (0, 0, 1) + t (0, 1, 0)$ and $\ell$ via $t \mapsto (0, 0, 1) + t (1, -1, -1)$, so it suffices to find $T$ that maps $(0, 1, 0)$ to $(1, -1, 1)$ and fixes $(0, 0, 1)$, and thus we may take, e.g., $$T := \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&-1&0\\0&-1&1} .$$

The choices we made above produced $T, \pi, S$ with many zero entries, making $\phi$ fast to compute by hand:
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\phi = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&-1&0\\1&-4&1}}} .$$

Comment: Thanks! Brief yet effective :)

Comment: I have one question. I was comparing your solution to @Fimpellizieri's and I couldn't understand why the two resulting matrices differ.

Comment: Thanks! Since you mentioned the problem arose in a test environment, I tried to produce a solution that was efficient to carry out by hand. As for the solutions, there are infinitely many of them, and Fimpellizieri and I just happened to find two different ones. amd's solution---namely, the upper-left $3 \times 3$ minor of the last matrix in his solution, is yet another.

Comment: Any transformation $A:=\pmatrix{*&*&*\\*&*&*\\0&0&1}$ preserves $\Pi_0$, so any (rank $2$) map $T \circ \pi \circ A \circ S$ also maps $\Pi$ onto $\ell$ as required. For example, taking $A:=\pmatrix{*&*&*\\1&-2&-1\\0&0&1}$ recovers Fimpellizieri's solution.